# Nested while loop in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am trying to implement a loss function in keras such as in following pseudo code

```py
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        sum += some_calculations
```

but I read that tensor flow doesn't support such for loops hence I came to know about while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars) function from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop)

I understood the basic working of the while loop here hence I implemented  the following code:

```py
def body1(i):
    global data
    N = len(data)*positive_samples     //Some length
    j = tf.constant(0)    //iterators
    condition2 = lambda j, i :tf.less(j, N)   //one condition only j should be less than N
    tf.add(i, 1)   //increment previous index i
    result = 0

    def body2(j, i):
        global similarity_matrix, U, V
        result = (tf.transpose(U[:, i])*V[:, j])   //U and V are 2-d tensor Variables and here only a column is extracted and their final product is a single value
        return result

    tf.while_loop(condition2, body2, loop_vars=[j, i])
    return result


def loss_function(x):
    global data
    N = len(data)*positive_samples
    i = tf.constant(0)
    condition1 =  lambda i : tf.less(i, N)
    return tf.while_loop(condition1, body1, [i])
```

But when I am running this code i am getting an error

```py
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same number of elements. First structure: [<tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/while/while/Identity:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/while/while/Identity_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>], second structure: [0]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) can be tricky to use, make sure to read the documentation carefully. The return value of the body must have the same structure than the loop variables, and the return value of the `tf.while_loop` operation is the final value of the variables. In order to make a computation, you should pass an additional loop variable to store the partial results. You could do something like this:

```py
def body1(i, result):
    global data
    N = len(data) * positive_samples
    j = tf.constant(0)
    condition2 = lambda j, i, result: tf.less(j, N)
    result = 0

    def body2(j, i, result):
        global similarity_matrix, U, V
        result_j = (tf.transpose(U[:, i]) * V[:, j])
        return j + 1, i, result + result_j

    j, i, result = tf.while_loop(condition2, body2, loop_vars=[j, i, result])
    return i + 1, result

def loss_function(x):
    global data
    N = len(data)*positive_samples
    i = tf.constant(0)
    result = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
    condition1 = lambda i, result: tf.less(i, N)
    i, result = tf.while_loop(condition1, body1, [i, result])
    return result
```

It is not clear from your code where `x` is to be used. In this case, though, the result of the operation should be equal to simply:

```py
result = tf.reduce_sum(tf.linalg.matmul(U, V, transpose_a=True))
```

Which will also be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more example of a nested loop in TensorFlow using `tf.while_loop`.
In this one, ith element of the tensor x are iteratively concatenated by the number of times given in the ith element of the tensor v.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])
v = tf.constant([1,2,3])
i = tf.constant(0)
a_combined = tf.zeros([0, 2], dtype=tf.int32)


def body(x,v,i,a_combined):
    x_slice = tf.slice(x,[i,0], [1, x.shape[1]])
    v_slice = tf.slice(v,[i],[1])
    j = tf.constant(0)
    b_combined = tf.zeros([0, 2], dtype=tf.int32)
    
    print("i: ", i)
    
    def body_supp(x_slice,v_slice,j, b_combined):
        
        print("j: ", j)
        
        j = tf.add(j,1)
        b_combined = tf.concat([b_combined,x_slice],0)
        return x_slice, v_slice, j, b_combined 
    
    while_condition_supp = lambda x_slice, v_slice, j, b_combined: tf.less(j, v_slice)
    
    x_slice, v_slice, j, b_combined = tf.while_loop(while_condition_supp, body_supp, [x_slice, v_slice, j, b_combined])
    
    i = tf.add(i,1)

    a_combined = tf.concat([a_combined,b_combined],0)
    return x, v, i, a_combined

while_condition = lambda x, v, i, a_combined: i < v.shape[0]  

x, v, i, a_combined = tf.while_loop(while_condition, body, [x, v, i, a_combined])

a_combined
```

Output would look like this:

```html
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 3]], dtype=int32)>
```